# Is it possible rewrite php file using fwrite without removing php comments?

Tags: php, fwrite

I have some php file and it contains some comments.

```
<?php
    $test = array(
     'LBL_TEXT' => 'text',//test comment
     'LBL_FOO' => 'foo'  
    );
```

Now I need to update 'LBL_TEXT' value(text) above file without removing comment('//test comment'). Is it possible using fwrite() or some other way.

Comment: What prevents you from using any text-editor to edit the file as desired?

Comment: It is possible, but not easy.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Its my typo mistake. I updated. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome and I had to be sure. You would be amazed as to what people really use sometimes ;-)

Comment: @MBaas I have hundreds of similar files to update with content. I am writing an automated script to do this work instead of doing this manually

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but these links could be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385977/preg-replace-with-two-arrays and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553860/using-preg-replace-on-a-array - I have a pretty good idea as to what you want to do and how to achieve it, but it would take a while for me to write something out. Regex expressions would be something to use.

Answer (score 0):

So you will need something like

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("foo.php");
$data = so something clever to automatically change string as desired;
file_put_contents("foo.php",$data);

?>
```